# Are the derivatives of the differential entropy power alternating?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb {R}^d$ and $X_t = X + \sqrt {t} N$, $t >0$, where $N$ is an independent
standard normal vector; set
$$
    H(X_t) = - \int f_t \ln f_t dx
$$
where $f_t$ is the density of the law of $X_t$. The entropy power of $X_t$ is defined as
$$
    N(t) = N(X_t) = e^{(2/d) H(X_t)}, \quad t >0.
$$
It is known that $N'(t) \geq 0$, $N''(t) \leq 0$ (Costa's inequality)
and $N'''(t) \geq 0$ whenever the law of $X$ is log-concave (Toscani). Could it be that the signs of the
successive derivatives of $N$ are alternating?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you mean to ask this question: Does there exist a random vector $X$ such that $(-1)^{k-1}N^{(k)}>0$ for all $k=1,2,\dots$?

Comment: This should hold for any $X$. (Clearly if $X$ is Gaussian, the result holds true since the entropy power is then linear in $t$.)

Comment: I guess you might already know, but this is closely related to McKean's conjecture, a weak form of which speculates that the successive derivatives of $H(X_t)$ alternate in sign.  See "Higher Order Derivatives in Costa’s Entropy Power Inequality" by Cheng and Geng, and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment, you can take a look at the discussion in section 1.6.5 of the book [Entropy Methods for the Boltzmann Equation: Lectures from a Special Semester at the Centre Émile Borel, Institut H. Poincaré, Paris, 2001](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=K3meGQ9ntjgC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Entropy+Methods+for+the+Boltzmann+Equation:+Lectures+from+a+Special+Semester+at+the+Centre+%C3%89mile+Borel,+Institut+H.+Poincar%C3%A9,+Paris,+2001&ots=5pSxcu8IoU&sig=qDslvEYDP1ggdYT-W-w5Pj3iwDg#v=onepage&q=Entropy%20Methods%20for%20the%20Boltzmann%20Equation%3A%20Lectures%20from%20a%20Special%20Semester%20at%20the%20Centre%20%C3%89mile%20Borel%2C%20Institut%20H.%20Poincar%C3%A9%2C%20Paris%2C%202001&f=false) where C. Villani discussed the so-called "super-$H$-theorem". The takeaway is that for most of the models coming from mathematical physics, such conjecture is downright false.

Answer (score 1):

Michel Ledoux discusses this as the "completely monotone conjecture" in his paper [Differentials of entropy and Fisher information along heat flow: a brief review of some conjectures](https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/ledoux/files/2023/03/Entropy-conjectures.pdf)